# User exists function does not work?

Tags: php

I have the following function to check if the username already exists:

```
function user_exist($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)FROM  `adver` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

And this is my error code:

```
if (user_exist($user_data['username']) === true) {
    $errors[] = '- sorry, the  \'' . $user_data['username'] . '\' exists.';
}
```

But it's not working?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: **not working?**

*WHAT* is not working? Any error messages? More information needed here!

Comment: I'm not getting any error, and I can register a user name that already exists!

Comment: Don't use PHP for something that can easily be done in SQL via `UNIQUE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not getting any error, and I can register a user name that already exists!

Your function returns true if **only one instance** of the username is present in the database.  It returns false in all other cases.  Therefore, it will return false if the username has been registered multiple times already.

Also, it behooves any programmer to move away from `mysql_` functions.